# Need Help Choosing a FOSS License for a Swift Package With Specific Requirements

Tags: licensing, gpl, mit, apache-2.0, floss

Stack Overflow community!

I'm working on a Swift package and am having some trouble deciding which FOSS (Free and Open Source Software) license to use. I have specific requirements and am hoping someone can guide me in choosing the right license. Here's what I'm aiming for:

1. I want the code to be openly available and modifiable. Anyone should be able to use it, tweak it, or even port it to another language or platform like Kotlin on Android.
2. The package represents a barebones version of some business logic that can be "compiled and integrated as you see fit." On my end, I plan to use it in a closed-source, monetized iOS app. While I haven't decided if the iOS app will eventually be open-sourced, I want to leave that option open.

Given these conditions, what FOSS license(s) would you recommend? I've been considering the MIT, Apache 2.0, and GPL licenses, but I'm not sure which one would best fit my needs.

#### What I've Looked Into:

- **MIT License**: This seems to allow almost everything, but I'm not sure if it covers the future open-sourcing of the app that will use the package.
- **Apache 2.0**: This is similar to MIT but includes an explicit grant of patent rights. Would that be beneficial for my situation?
- **GPL**: I've read that using GPL code in closed-source applications can be problematic, so I'm hesitant to choose this one.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or advice on which license would best meet my needs.

---

**EDIT**

@phillip-kendall et al - I looked at the question that I am supposedly duplicating and I don't see how my question is duplicating a question about GPL ?  Please help me understand.  Thanks.

Comment: What restrictions do you want to impose on the users of your package? Should they be allowed to use it in a competing closed source app or only in open source applications? Must improvements be made open source or could they be made closed source?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau That's a great question! TBH, they would be allowed to use it in a competing closed source app.  However I would prefer if improvements to the open source Swift package would be made openly, so everyone (including myself) can benefit from it.

Comment: @dornad From my reading of your requirements, you seem to think that releasing your code under an open source license could somehow prevent you using it in your closed source application; the duplicate explains why that is not the case.